# Get all methods of an Objective-C class or instance

Tags: objective-c, introspection, objective-c-runtime

In Objective-C I can test whether a given class or instance responds to certain selectors. But how can query a class or instance for all its methods or properties of a class (e.g. a list of all methods or properties)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to use the Objective C runtime methods, see here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/objective_c_runtime

Comment: This link now redirects to navigation page

Comment: Apples docs have gotten more horrible.  Buzzy's answer below is a much better answer.

Answer (score 65):

In addition to Buzzy's answer, for debugging purposes you may use the `-[NSObject _methodDescription]` private method.

Either in lldb:

```
(lldb) po [[UIApplication sharedApplication] _methodDescription]
```

or in code:

```
@interface NSObject (Private)
- (NSString*)_methodDescription;
@end

// Somewhere in the code:
NSLog(@"%@", [objectToInspect performSelector:@selector(_methodDescription)]);
```

Output will look as following:

```
<__NSArrayM: 0x7f9 ddc4359a0>:
in __NSArrayM:
    Class Methods:
        + (BOOL) automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:(id)arg1; (0x11503b510)
        + (id) allocWithZone:(_NSZone*)arg1; (0x11503b520)
        + (id) __new:::::(const id*)arg1; (0x114f0d700)
    Instance Methods:
        - (void) removeLastObject; (0x114f669a0)
        - (void) dealloc; (0x114f2a8f0)
        - (void) finalize; (0x11503b2c0)
        - (id) copyWithZone:(_NSZone*)arg1; (0x114f35500)
        - (unsigned long) count; (0x114f0d920)
        - (id) objectAtIndex:(unsigned long)arg1; (0x114f2a730)
        - (void) getObjects:(id*)arg1 range:(_NSRange)arg2; (0x114f35650)
        - (void) addObject:(id)arg1; (0x114f0d8e0)
        - (void) setObject:(id)arg1 atIndex:(unsigned long)arg2; (0x114f99680)
        - (void) insertObject:(id)arg1 atIndex:(unsigned long)arg2; (0x114f0d940)
        - (void) exchangeObjectAtIndex:(unsigned long)arg1 withObjectAtIndex:(unsigned long)arg2; (0x114f8bf80)
        ......
in NSMutableArray:
    Class Methods:
        + (id) copyNonRetainingArray; (0x11ee20178)
        + (id) nonRetainingArray; (0x11ee201e8)
        + (id) nonRetainingArray; (0x120475026)
        + (id) arrayWithCapacity:(unsigned long)arg1; (0x114f74280)
        ......
```

Comment: Best answer so far

Comment: It looks like this method has been renamed to `fp_methodDescription` (also `fp_shortMethodDescription` and `fp_ivarDescription`).

Comment: `fp_methodDescription` lists inherited methods too, up to and including NSObject.  `fp_shortMethodDescription` does not list inherited methods.

Answer (score 52):

You can do this and it is extremely well documented at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html

To fetch all the instance or class methods of a class, you may use `class_copyMethodList` and iterate over the results. An example:

```
 #import <objc/runtime.h>

/**
 *  Gets a list of all methods on a class (or metaclass)
 *  and dumps some properties of each
 *
 *  @param clz the class or metaclass to investigate
 */
void DumpObjcMethods(Class clz) {

    unsigned int methodCount = 0;
    Method *methods = class_copyMethodList(clz, &methodCount);

    printf("Found %d methods on '%s'\n", methodCount, class_getName(clz));

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < methodCount; i++) {
        Method method = methods[i];

        printf("\t'%s' has method named '%s' of encoding '%s'\n",
               class_getName(clz),
               sel_getName(method_getName(method)),
               method_getTypeEncoding(method));

        /**
         *  Or do whatever you need here...
         */
    }

    free(methods);
}
```

You will need to make two separate calls to this method. One for the instance methods and another for the class methods:

```
/**
 *  This will dump all the instance methods
 */
DumpObjcMethods(yourClass);
```

Calling the same on the metaclass will give you all the class methods

```
/**
 *  Calling the same on the metaclass gives you
 *  the class methods
 */
DumpObjcMethods(object_getClass(yourClass) /* Metaclass */);
```

Comment: The import path is hard to find, use:  #import <objc/runtime.h>

Comment: Thanks, may be a typo,

"DumpObjcMethods(object_getClass(yourClass) /* Metaclass */);"

should be:

"DumpObjcMethods(object_getMetaClass(yourClass) /* Metaclass */);"

Comment: @Joey: I don't think there is a typo there. There is no routine called `object_getMetaClass`. The class objects class is its meta class.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible via objc_method_list. In order to enumerate your methods, you will have to register all your methods before hand.

The process is straight forward: after you've declared your function you can create an instance of objc_method and register the function name. Then add the objc_method to a objc_method_list and finally pass the objc_method_list to class_addMethods..

Here is a link to get you started:
http://theocacao.com/document.page/327