# How can I check if a class implements all methods in a protocol in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, protocols

If an object conforms to a certain protocol in Objective-C, is there a way to check if it conforms all the methods in that protocol. I would rather avoid explicitly checking each available method.

Thanks

Comment: Protocol methods are required by default, so if a class adopts a given protocol, it should implement all those methods that aren't marked `@optional`.

Comment: @NoahWitherspoon I am not asking how to check for conformance to a protocol. I'm asking how to check if the methods in the actual protocol are all implemented.

Comment: Maybe by having a loop which calls respondsToSelector for each method of the protocol. And to have methods of the protocol, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094702/get-all-methods-of-an-objective-c-class-or-instance

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It's about checking whether classes actually implement the methods declared in a protocol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all methods declared in a protocol with `protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList`, which returns a pointer to `objc_method_description` structs.

`objc_method_description` is defined in `objc/runtime.h`:

```
struct objc_method_description {
    SEL name;               /**< The name of the method */
    char *types;            /**< The types of the method arguments */
};
```

To find out if instances of a class respond to a selector use `instancesRespondToSelector:`

Leaving you with a function like this:

```
BOOL ClassImplementsAllMethodsInProtocol(Class class, Protocol *protocol) {
    unsigned int count;
    struct objc_method_description *methodDescriptions = protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList(protocol, NO, YES, &count);
    BOOL implementsAll = YES;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<count; i++) {
        if (![class instancesRespondToSelector:methodDescriptions[i].name]) {
            implementsAll = NO;
            break;
        }
    }
    free(methodDescriptions);
    return implementsAll;
}
```

Comment: Memory leak if the class doesn't implements all the methods of the protocol, add free(methodDescrptions); before return NO; or even better add a flag and break the loop instead when not found.

Comment: Guys one word...badass. Thanks Sebastian for this awesome answer and thanks @Johnmph for the follow up comment.

Comment: @Johnmph Thanks, good catch! I updated my answer to a single return statement.