# Converting NSCalendarDate to xml file and back returns __NSTaggedDate

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, osx-mavericks

In Objective-C (OS X 10.9) I write an NSDictionary to file with `[MyDict writeToFile:SavePath atomically:YES];`. I restore the dictionary with `MyDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];`

But I then encounter that a key that contains an object of NSCalendarDate is no longer an NSCalendarDate, but a __NSTaggedDate. This gives me the following error:

```
2016-09-06 09:19:39.957 MyProject[720:303] -[__NSTaggedDate yearOfCommonEra]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x41bd7801f000000d
```

On the line of code:

```
if([AtTansaction.TransactionDate yearOfCommonEra]    == DataArray[cnt].year)
```

So how to reconstruct an NSCalendarDate? What is the NSTaggedDate?

Comment: Where exactly did you find class named NSCalendarDate ? Is it in iOS api ?  Probably you are trying to mention NSDate. You dont really need to care about what NSTaggedDate is. It might be some internal representation of the class.

Comment: @Sandeep It's tagged with OS X, `NSCalendarDate` inherits from `NSDate`.

Comment: `NSCalendarDate` is deprecated. *Use of NSCalendarDate strongly
discouraged. For calendrical calculations, you should
use suitable combinations of NSCalendar, NSDate, and  NSDateComponents, as described in Calendars in Dates and Times Programming Topics for Cocoa*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the mistake. NSDictionary only saves `NSDate`s, not `NSCalendarDate`s. The object returned is an `__NSTaggedDate`, which inherits from `NSDate`. I found this by calling: [DumpObjcMethods(object_getClass(_StartDate))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094702/get-all-methods-of-an-objective-c-class-or-instance) on the object and its superclass:

```
Found 9 methods on '__NSTaggedDate'
'__NSTaggedDate' has method named 'dealloc' of encoding 'v16@0:8'
'__NSTaggedDate' has method named 'timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate' of encoding 'd16@0:8'
'__NSTaggedDate' has method named 'initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:' of encoding '@24@0:8d16'
'__NSTaggedDate' has method named 'isInToday' of encoding 'c16@0:8'
'__NSTaggedDate' has method named 'isInTomorrow' of encoding 'c16@0:8'
'__NSTaggedDate' has method named 'isInYesterday' of encoding 'c16@0:8'
'__NSTaggedDate' has method named 'isInSameDayAsDate:' of encoding 'c24@0:8@16'
'__NSTaggedDate' has method named 'isEqual:toUnitGranularity:' of encoding 'c32@0:8@16Q24'
'__NSTaggedDate' has method named 'compare:toUnitGranularity:' of encoding 'q32@0:8@16Q24'
```

Luckily, I can convert `NSDate`s (and thus `__NSTaggedDate`) to `NSCalendarDate` with _StartDate = [NSCalendarDate dateWithTimeInterval:0 sinceDate:_StartDate];