# Importing custom iOS framework into two different Xcode projects don't get same result

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I am facing some issues on the last two days and I didn't find anything on Internet that help me to solve them.

Here's the problem:

- I have a custom iOS framework of my own
- I have two different Xcode projects that use this custom framework
- In the first project, there is no problem, everything works perfectly
- In the second project, I get a *Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[** **:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101b02f90'* when I am calling a method which is also called in the first project and which works perfectly in the first project
- Both projects use the same custom iOS framework version and build

During the last two days, I have tried the followings:

- Clean project > Clean build project > Rebuild project - Doesn't work
- Rebuild the framework and add into the two projects - The issue still there

One thing that is very weird is that I have print the methods available in my frameworks in both projects according to this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094702/get-all-methods-of-an-objective-c-class-or-instance?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), in the first project I have **130** methods available, in the second one I have only **72** methods available.

Is anyone have a clue of what happen?

Regards,

Jeremy

Comment: is it objc? or swift? on objc you might need to add for loading the -load_all or -force_load on the projects loading it so you get the symbols...?

Comment: The apps are in swift, the framework is in objc. Where I should add this flags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sry, I just saw you first question/answer now.

The main reason you need to do that is because of categories or other dynamic elements in static libraries. Objective C has Categories which are approximately the same as extensions in Swift, so you can extend classes/objects with additional methods.

In Objective C you can create a static library to link into you project. Without this flag however (-ObjC general of -force_load for a specific library) the symbols of Categories are not loaded outside of the library. I guess an original motivation was to use categories for internal stuff, so the default is not to load them. That also makes the binary a bit smaller. However many libraries actually add Categories (==Extension) they want to expose, so usually you need on of the flags.

Hope that helped a bit ^_^.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find out what was causing the issue. I need to add *-ObjC* flag in "Other Linker Flags" in the Build Settings of the second project.

I don't understand why without this flag the framework has only 72 methods, and with the flags all the methods are available. Someone has an idea?

Comment: btw.: If my answer above helped you, maybe you could accept it as answer?